# Remove Row from UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, core-data, nsmutablearray

Please read before marking as duplicate....

I am currently trying to remove rows from a `UITableView` but without any result.

I have a delete button on the cell of the `UITableView`. Once selected i hope to remove that row.

When the delete button is selected it calls the following method

```
- (void)didClickOnCellAtIndex:(NSInteger)cellIndex withData:(id)data
{


    [self.mainTableView beginUpdates];

    NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:cellIndex inSection:0];
   //
    [self.mainTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:path] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
   [filteredSubArrayForExpandableSection removeObjectAtIndex:cellIndex];
    [appDelegate.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:path]];
    [appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:nil];
     [self.mainTableView endUpdates];

   //
    // Save the context.
    NSError *error;
    if (![appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        /*
         Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

         abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. If it is not possible to recover from the error, display an alert panel that instructs the user to quit the application by pressing the Home button.
         */

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
       // abort();
    }
}
```

The above code will return the following issue

> Reason: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The
>   number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (8)
>   must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before
>   the update (8), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted
>   from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number
>   of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out)

When i reload the app the row still remains.

Ok so the number of rows in this case should be 7!

So logically I added the following code in between the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` method.

```
    numberOfRows = numberOfRows - 1;
```

This however returns the following error

> -[ViewController deleteRow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a278a00 (lldb)

I can load up the app and the row has been deleted as it should but obviously the app crashed out prior to this.

if i remove the `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` method from the `didClick` method and use the following `NSFetchedController` Delegate method i get the exact same above issues

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert: {
            [self.mainTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete: {

            [self.mainTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate: {
            //[self configureCell:(TSPToDoCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            NSLog(@"results changed update called");
            break;
        }
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove: {
            [self.mainTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            [self.mainTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

number of rows method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

        if (canExpand) {
         //if can expand section becomes top row for expansion effect thus we need to add 1 to show ALL rows
            return numberOfRows + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            //if cannot expand section we remove 1 from total

            return numberOfRows -1 ;
        }

        return 0  ;
}
```

any help regarding this will be greatly received

Thanks

Comment: What does your implementation of `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` look like?

Comment: thanks for the quick response Avi... in NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete :-if i delete the row in the delegate before deleteRowsAtIndex i get the -[ViewController deleteRow:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance error if i place it after i get nvalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update.... error

Comment: If you are using UITableView with NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods then you should only call the Core Data methods to delete the object.  Do not call any methods to make changes to the UITableView itself because the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods take care of that for you.   Otherwise you have to methods doing updates and things get out of sync as the error message indicates.  Make sure you implement the delegate methods exactly as shown in the Apple docs.

Comment: How is numberOfRows changed?  You would probably be better off using the FRC's methods to get the number of sections and rows per section.  That's one of the purposes of the FRC.

Comment: You need to delete the data/object from filteredSubArrayForExpandableSection first before calling deleteRowsAtIndexPaths: .

Comment: Reducing the number of rows seems right.  When you crash on the `unrecognized selector`, what does the stack trace look like?  Specifically, what's calling `[ViewController deleteRow:]`?

Comment: You should explain `filteredSubarrayForExpandableSection`. Am I right to guess that this keeps track of possible additional rows underneath the FRC powered rows? If so, it looks like a faulty data setup.

Comment: No, it's a mutable array of objects with a predication applied. So for example it filters a key with a given string.